# How to get a Google managed certificate (ingress)? I received no matches for "ManagedCertificate"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been following the document (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) to get Google managed ssl.

It was successfully before. However, after I completely deleted my cluster and started it over, I received this error message from

```
kubectl apply -f example-certificate.yaml
```

```
error: unable to recognize "example-certificate.yaml": no matches for 
kind "ManagedCertificate" in version "networking.gke.io/v1beta1"
```

I re-installed Kubernetes with the latest Kubernetes.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.9-dispatcher", GitCommit:"e3f5193e8f1091a162af7e17a781e6a3129bcfd0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-28T18:15:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.7-gke.12", GitCommit:"06f08e60069231bd21bdf673cf0595aac80b99f6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-25T20:37:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Then, I created a reserved external IP address.

```
gcloud compute addresses create example-ip-address --global
```

After that, I'm still facing the same issue. I spent many hours to find a document about the error message, but couldn't find any clue about the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You chose a old version for your cluster.
The current default version 1.11.7-gke.12 does not support it.
Just upgrade your cluster.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine with the latest cluster version (1.12.6-gke.10). The document has no mention about that :(

Comment: I see the following in the docs: "Note: Managed certificates require clusters with masters running Kubernetes 1.12.6-gke.7 or higher."

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue on GKE cluster v 1.15.9-gke.24
Using apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1 solved it for me.

Comment: I just experienced the same. Thanks @Hari

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, as @Victor G. said, upgrading my master to 1.12.6-gke.10 fixed the problem.